# What html tag to use to insert posts in a database that are shown elsewhere?

Tags: php, html, posts, paragraph, pre

I'm trying to build a sort of a diary web application where the user can insert entries into a textarea that are then inserted into the database and if they go to their home page they can see their entries. Now my problem is, I tried showing the entry body as a "pre" tag so as to preserve spaces and all, but then each paragraph of an entry inserted shows as one long line of text in the home page, without any line breaks, which naturally messes up the page. Any ideas on how to get around that? Thanks.

Comment: Post what you've got thus far.

Comment: Avoid using <pre>. The php nl2br() will convert new lines back. Just put replace the \t (s) found in the string for some tag that can represent tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using CSS if you'd like. Please see this example with a 100px width:

```
pre {
    width: 100px;
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Comment: …and you could also use this on semantic markup, e.g. `p` when dealing with paragraphs.